# Blank page when using swaggo/http-swagger with julienschmidt/httprouter

Tags: go, swagger

I am making an api and used swaggo/swag to build a swagger interface. Previously, I used the net/http package, and everything was working fine.

I switched to julienschmidt/httprouter, but I don't manage to make the swagger interface work again. Here is my code

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter"
    httpSwagger "github.com/swaggo/http-swagger"
)

func main() {
    router := httprouter.New()

    router.ServeFiles("/api/doc/static/*filepath", http.Dir("api/swagger/static"))
    router.HandlerFunc(http.MethodGet, "/api/doc/index.html", swaggerHandler)
    // router.HandlerFunc(http.MethodGet, "/api/doc", swaggerHandler)

    fmt.Println("Server on port 8080")
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", router))
}

func swaggerHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    swaggerFileUrl := "http://localhost:8080/api/doc/static/swagger.json"
    handler := httpSwagger.Handler(httpSwagger.URL(swaggerFileUrl))
    handler.ServeHTTP(w, r)
}
```

I checked if `swaggerFileUrl` variable is correct, and I am able to access the json file with this url. The interface is a complete blank page titled "Swagger UI". Because the title is replaced, I am assuming, that *something* happened, but I don't know if the issue comes from httpSwagger or httprouter.

Edit: Issue is caused because javascript files loading the interface are not present. See this [github issue](https://github.com/swaggo/http-swagger/issues/10)

Answer (score 5):

You can do it like this:

```
routes := httprouter.New()

routes.GET("/doc/:any", swaggerHandler)


func swaggerHandler(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request, p httprouter.Params) {
     httpSwagger.WrapHandler(res, req)
}
```

Do not forget import doc files

```
import (
     _ "example.project/docs"
)
```